# Start Electron/Node.JS app and pass command line args from C#

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, command-line-arguments, electron

I have a C# application which launches an Electron app (node.js). I'm attempting to pass a command line argument to the Node.JS application but when I access process.argv from within index.js the argument isn't there. Is there anything specific I should be doing to retrieve this argument from within my node application?

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = pathToEXE;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = argument;
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.Start();
```

Comment: can you show your pathToEXE variable content?

Comment: it's a relative path to the node application executable, and it launches fine - I just can't seem to find where the argument went

Answer (score 0):

Basically `process.argv` array returns 2 values which are installed location and file opening path. So first of all you should assign those values in global object in `main.js` as below,

> global.sharedObject = { installedLocation: process.argv[0], openFilePath:
>   process.argv[1]}

and access this in your `index.js` as below,

> var remote = require('electron').remote;
>
> var location = remote.getGlobal('sharedObject').installedLocation;
>
> var filePath = remote.getGlobal('sharedObject').openFilePath;